# How to allow spanish letters in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here I have a text box and I want to allow spanish vowels such as ¨áéióú¨ and all spanish letters. I have return the javascript function as follows.

```
if ((key > 64 && key < 91)|| (key > 159 && key < 166) || (key > 96 && key < 123) || (key == 165) ||(key == 32)
                    || (key == 164) || (key == 130) || (key == 181) || (key == 144) || (key == 214) ||
                    (key == 224) ||(key == 233) || (key == 8) || (key == 241) || (key == 209)) {
            }else{
                event.preventDefault();
            }
```

I have allowed the ñ and Ñ Beacuse Those letters are present in Keyboard. So I debugged the code And I found the keycodes and I allowed them. For the other letters I canot able to find the keycodes. Can any one help me to find the keycodes for the spanish letters
.

Comment: @JaromandaX I have done the same. But I dont have the same keywords in the keyboard

Comment: FWIW, "keywords" has a very specific meaning when talking about programming languages (which has nothing to do with what you are using the term for).

Comment: @JaromandaX I might explained wrongly. I too have letters only. I dont have letters áéióú directly in my keyboard

Comment: How do you get *key*? Is it a string? Modifier keys (shift, alt, control, command, etc.) affect the character that is generated when a particular key is pressed. Also, you can't reliably map the key that is pressed to the character that is generated since different keyboards have different mappings.

Comment: @JaromandaX mine is english keyboard

Comment: spanish 'i' is not there in my keyboard

Comment: @JaromandaX  this textbox is allowing ñ. because I allowed them in the function. But I am not able to find the keycodes for the áéíóú

Comment: Not at all, I am doing the same now

Comment: oh, so those codes in your code snippet don't work - sorry, I really misunderstood the question

Comment: KEYWORDS??? really???

Comment: Don't try to parse keyCodes to get characters, especially these ones, which are often the combination of two characters like on my French keyboard, I use `~` + `n` to produce `ñ`. You can't get it from keycode, nor from `key`, because `~` is reported a `'Dead'` key, and is only activated after I pressed an combinator 'alt'  key. And this will be different on each keyboard's layouts Instead, simply listen for the `input` event, and do the validation over the actual value of your input, not over what it could be.

Comment: @SanjeevPrasadThakur what do you mean?

Comment: i edited your question changed keyword word to letter..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just restrict only letters that you don't want to allow  present in your keyboard. If you enter other than that letters it will be allowed